# Using regex (re.search) in a python list

Tags: python, regex, list

I have the following code

```
import re

pattern = ['A-minor Type I AGC', 'A-minor Type I AGC', 'A-minor Type I AGC', 'A-minor Type I AUA', 'A-minor Type I AUA', 'A-minor Type II AGC', 'A-minor Type II AGC']

n = len(pattern)
print pattern
pattern_str = ', '.join(pattern)
print pattern_str
for x in range(0, n):
    if re.search(r'\bType I\b', pattern_str):
        print "Hello Type I"
    elif re.search(r'\bType II\b', pattern_str):
        print "Hello Type II"
    else:
        print "An error has occured"
```

The desired output should be:

```
Hello Type I
Hello Type I
Hello Type I
Hello Type I
Hello Type I
Hello Type II
Hello Type II
```

But I'm not getting the desired output. My current output is:

```
Hello Type I
Hello Type I
Hello Type I
Hello Type I
Hello Type I
Hello Type I
Hello Type I
```

Can someone point out the problem? I suspect it has to be something to do with the list to str conversion. I have managed to solve the problem using the following code:

```
for x in pattern:
    if re.search(r'\bType I\b', x):
        print "Hello Type I"
    elif re.search(r'\bType II\b', x):
        print "Hello Type II"
    else:
        print "An error has occured"
```

But I would like to know why my first code didn't work and how can I make it work. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Well - you initialized the pattern_str only once in the list and that's why you are getting the result. You could do - what you've done (more correct) or following change `for x in range(0,n): pattern_str = pattern[x]`

Comment: @gabhijit Thank you very much for your answer. Your advice to change pattern_str = pattern[x] made the first code to work. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What you want**: search through each string in your list.

**What your code does**

```
re.search(r'\bType I\b', pattern_str)
```

It searches through pattern_str in every iteration of the loop. What is pattern_str:

```
pattern_str = ', '.join(pattern)
```

Thus, in every iteration, it searches through the same string, which is the concatanation of the whole list, which always matches Type I in `A-minor Type I AGC`.

Changing in to search through each `x` in `pattern` does the trick

Answer (score 2):

You're joining the whole list into a single string, then testing that a whole bunch of times.  Instead, what you want is to test each string in the list like

```
for pattern_str in pattern:
    if re.search(r'\bType I\b', pattern_str):
        print "Hello Type I"
    elif re.search(r'\bType II\b', pattern_str):
        print "Hello Type II"
    else:
        print "An error has occured"
```

so you are searching each pattern, one at a time

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is the same for each iteration. You need to loop through your patterns in your for-loop.

Use `for p in pattern`

This will mean `p` is `'A-minor Type I AGC'` on the first iteration, `'A-minor Type I AGC'` on the second iteration, etc.

```
import re

pattern = ['A-minor Type I AGC', 'A-minor Type I AGC', 'A-minor Type I AGC', 'A-minor Type I AUA', 'A-minor Type I AUA', 'A-minor Type II AGC', 'A-minor Type II AGC']

for p in pattern:
    if re.search(r'\bType I\b', p):
        print "Hello Type I"
    elif re.search(r'\bType II\b', p):
        print "Hello Type II"
    else:
        print "An error has occured"
```

Output:

```
Hello Type I
Hello Type I
Hello Type I
Hello Type I
Hello Type I
Hello Type II
Hello Type II
```